# Convert object to IEnumerable of anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, anonymous-types

How do I iterate over the `anonymous type` that is passed in as an object below  `(first, second, third) => new { One = first, Two = second, Three = third }`

If I interrogate the type of message and print it, it says:`<>f__AnonymousType0 3[MtApi.MtQuote,MtApi.MtQuote,MtApi.MtQuote]`

```
//**How do I convert an object to the anonymous type?**
static void ShowAnonymousTypeMessage(object message)
{    

    foreach(var quote in message)
    Console.WriteLine(
        quote.Instrument + ": " + quote.Bid.ToString() + quote.Ask.ToString());
}
```

...

```
var pattern = observable1.And(observable2).And(observable3);
var plan = pattern.Then((first, second, third) => new { One = first, Two = second, Three = third });
var zippedSequence = Observable.When(plan);
zippedSequence.Subscribe(
    ShowAnonymousTypeMessage                
);
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and interrogate pattern to see what type it is and if it implements IEnumerable?

Comment: In C#<=6, you could do that with `dynamic` but this is really not what anonymous types are for, and `dynamic` isn't meant to turn C# into JavaScript. If you're passing it to a method, it should have a real type. Even a Tuple would be something.

Comment: @ kevin see original post

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) programming guide says, "you cannot declare a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as having an anonymous type. To pass an anonymous type ... as an argument to a method, you can declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the purpose of strong typing. If you must store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type."

Comment: @ed yeah a tuple would work since that is easily handled.

Comment: @Ivan This is almost certainly a situation where you should just create an object.

Comment: However, I just tried a signature of `dynamic theAnonymousType` instead of `object theAnonymousType` and it works fine.

Comment: @quantic, really? I changed it from object to dynamic and it excepts.

Comment: Uh I'll just post as an answer, maybe my super simple test is completely different than what you are doing.

Comment: Why not use a real object? Anonymous objects are really not great when they are being passed around between methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
static void Main()
{
    var anon = new { Name = "Terry", Age = 34 };
    test(anon);
}

static void test(dynamic t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Age);
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

Comment: What if you have several of them not just one?

Comment: @Ivan `void Test(dynamic d) { foreach (dynamic item in d) { /* stuff */ }` -- tested, works.

Comment: Aha! Thanks that is what I am missing.

Comment: @Ivan But for the love of God write a quickie class, or at least use a Tuple.

Comment: Agreed. Dynamic seems overkill here.

Comment: @Ivan I'd call it underkill, myself.

Comment: Or maybe Road Kill

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types aren't intended to be passed around and you should only use object when absolutely necessary. Also you can't iterate over an anonymous type - you should use an `Array`.

```
var pattern = observable1.And(observable2).And(observable3);
var plan = pattern.Then((first, second, third) => new[] { first, second, third });
var zippedSequence = Observable.When(plan);
zippedSequence.Subscribe(
    ShowAnonymousTypeMessage                
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types aren't meant to be passed around, for the same reason we have strong typing in C# at all: The compiler doesn't make careless errors or forget things, and we often do. If your anonymous class instances are leaving the scope where they were created, it's time for them to grow up and be a real class.

Usually I'd say you should write a quickie class with appropriate properties (guessing at the property types here):

```
public class Thing {
    public String One { get; set; }
    public String Two { get; set; }
    public String Three { get; set; }
}
```

But a `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>` is just as good really, if you've got property names like `One`, `Two`, and `Three` anyway:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(n => new Tuple<int, string>(n, $"Item {n + 1}"));

    Test(x);
}

private static void Test(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, string>> stuff)
{
    foreach (var item in stuff)
    {
        Console.Write($"{item.Item1}: {item.Item2}");
    }
}
```

`dynamic` works, but `dynamic` is like the Vise-Grip: "Always the Wrong Tool for Every Job, Since 1921". `dynamic` has a legitimate but small role in the typesystem. It's not there so we can turn the whole language into JavaScript.

```
public static Main()
{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(n => new { ID = n, Value = $"Item {n + 1}" });

    Test(x);
}

private static void Test(dynamic message)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in message)
    {
        Console.Write($"{item.ID}: {item.Value}");
    }
}
```

OK, the Vise-Grip isn't *always* the wrong tool either. But it's rare there isn't a better one.